# How to use regexp in TCL to match a line from a file?

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL. So I am asked to extract the start date from a file but I tried and there is no output. Please help.

From my file,there is this line i want to extract the start date:

```
Running final_step.step_done at: Wed Oct 11 02:04:03 MYT 2017
```

My code:

```
proc extract_data {} {
    ## To extract startdate 
    set file [open files/stages.files]
    while {[gets $file line] >= 0} {
        if {[regexp {^Running (\S+\s)at: (\S+.*)$} $line match Stage StartDate]} {
            if {[regexp "[$CURRENT_STAGE]\.step_done" $Stage]} {
                #set stage $Stage
                                set end_date $StartDate
                set print_end_date [regsub -all " " $StartDate "_"]
                                #echo "2) $stage - $end_date"
            } elseif {[regexp "^[$CURRENT_STAGE] " $Stage]} {
                #set stage $Stage
                set start_date $StartDate
                set print_start_date [regsub -all " " $StartDate "_"]
                #echo "1) $stage - $start_date"
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my regexp?

Comment: Is there, or is there not, an asterisk at the beginning (and end) of the line you are looking for? If there is, `^Running` won't match the line.

Comment: There are no * in my codes. It seems the * is produced when i set the codes to italic form. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: After the first `if`, try outputting the `Stage` and `StartDate` variables? I feel like the issue really is with the next set of if blocks.

Comment: The variable `stage` captures the blank between the stage descriptor and the string "at:". The next invocation of `regexp` disregards the blank (`"[$CURRENT_STAGE]\.step_done"`) while the one in the `elseif` (`"^[$CURRENT_STAGE] "`) doesn't. If the blank is just separating the descriptor from the "at:" string, don't capture it. There should still be output from either of those, but this is something that is bound to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The main RE looks fine — `^Running (\S+\s)at: (\S+.*)$` does indeed match the line that you're talking about — *but* these RE matches look suspicious:

```
regexp "[$CURRENT_STAGE]\.step_done" $Stage
```

```
regexp "^[$CURRENT_STAGE] " $Stage
```

In particular, you've got a command substitution in there with the name of the command coming from a variable. That's… valid in some circumstances, but quite an advanced technique; are you *sure* that's what you want? Also, the `CURRENT_STAGE` variable appears to be undeclared. I'd expect one of these approaches to be more likely to work:

### Variable Substitution

Here, we're using the *qualified* version of the variable name. Note that the variable had better contain a valid regular expression fragment, and we need to double up the backslash (because we're in a double-quoted context and not a braced context; one backslash is for the basic Tcl language, and the other is for the RE engine).

```
regexp "$::CURRENT_STAGE\\.step_done" $Stage
```

```
regexp "^$::CURRENT_STAGE " $Stage
```

### Command Substitution

Here, we're calling a command to get the actual stage. The command had better return a valid RE fragment, and as before, we're doubling up the backslash.

```
regexp "[CURRENT_STAGE]\\.step_done" $Stage
```

```
regexp "^[CURRENT_STAGE] " $Stage
```

In general, in both cases you might consider wrapping the part of the RE that represents the current stage in `(?:`…`)`, as that doesn't really change the semantics much, but does mean that the RE fragment can use features like alternation safely. Not that it matters when the RE fragment is a simple thing like `final_step`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should be able to get a lot done with code like this:

```
while {[gets $file line] >= 0} {
    if {[string match Running $line]} {
        set Stage [lindex [split $line] 1]
        set StartDate [lindex [string trim [split $line :]] end]
        if {[string match *.step_done $Stage]} {
            set end_date $StartDate
            set print_end_date [string map {" " _} $StartDate]
        } else {
            set start_date $StartDate
            set print_start_date [string map {" " _} $StartDate]
        }
    }
}
```

That is,

- check if the line starts with "Running"
- get the string between "Running" and "at:" into `Stage`
- get the date string after ":" into `StartDate`
- check if there is a string tail of the form "step_done" after a period in `$Stage`
- if there is, set `end_date` to `$StartDate` and `print_end_date` to the same string with all blanks replaced with underscores
- if the tail is empty, do the same with `start_date` and `print_start_date`

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)